# Vaadin Spring scoped objects: is it possible to create a Vaadin unit test without starting up a servlet container?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, vaadin

[vaadin-spring](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-spring) introduces a couple of Spring scoped objects, the `vaadin-session` and the `vaadin-ui` scope. It is necessary to have these two scopes bound before referencing any Vaadin objects in your spring context if:

- they are decorated with the `@VaadinSessionScope` or `@UIScope` annotations, or
- they through some dependency chain reference any bean that is decorated this way.

All runs perfectly well when you start it up in a servlet container like jboss or tomcat. The question is:

**If you would like to load a spring application context that contains any of the vaadin beans so decorated for unit testing purposes, how can you create a minimal test that allows the context to be loaded and accessed without starting up a web application container?**

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC is very good at this but when you're using vaadin-spring it's not as straightforward - the relevant vaadin components are highly connected.

(The following example of how to construct a set of Vaadin components to allow access through the abovementioned scopes does not include configuration of the full container, just the minimum required to get a functioning application context.)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SpringConfigurationTest extends Assert {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan({ "org.example" }) // contains SomeClassReferencingASpringVaadinBean.class
    public static class Config {
    }

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    class MyDeploymentConfiguration extends DefaultDeploymentConfiguration {
        public MyDeploymentConfiguration(Class<?> servletClass, Properties initParameters) {
            super(servletClass, initParameters);
            initParameters.put(Constants.SERVLET_PARAMETER_UI_PROVIDER, DefaultUIProvider.class.getName());
        }
    }

    class MyVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet {
        @Override
        public String getServletName() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }

    class MyUI extends UI {
        @Override
        protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setupVaadinScopes() throws Exception {
        MyVaadinServlet vaadinServlet = new MyVaadinServlet();
        MyDeploymentConfiguration deploymentConfiguration = new MyDeploymentConfiguration(MyVaadinServlet.class,
                new Properties());
        VaadinServletService vaadinService = new VaadinServletService(vaadinServlet, deploymentConfiguration);
        VaadinServletRequest vaadinRequest = new VaadinServletRequest(new MockHttpServletRequest(), vaadinService);
        // creates vaadin session and vaadin ui, binds them to thread
        VaadinSession vaadinSession = vaadinService.findVaadinSession(vaadinRequest);
        Integer uiId = Integer.valueOf(vaadinSession.getNextUIid());
        UI ui = new MyUI();
        ui.setSession(vaadinSession);
        UI.setCurrent(ui);
        ui.doInit(vaadinRequest, uiId, null);
        vaadinSession.addUI(ui);
    }

    @Test
    public void test0() {
        try {
             applicationContext.getBean(SomeClassReferencingASpringVaadinBean.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("scopes were probably not set up correctly");
        }
    }

}
```